# In chat application how to send messages in public room in an efficient manner

Tags: c++, algorithm, architecture, client-server

I am creating a chat application based on Server/Client Architecture. Communication between Server and client is TCP based sockets. In this application I am creating different public rooms. Any number of users can join any Public room.

Now When a user in a public room lets say "XYZ" sends a message for the room I need to deliver that message to all people in "XYZ" public room.

Problem starts with here. Lets say there are 1000 users in public room "XYZ" and whenever a user send a message in this room I need to send this message to rest 999 people one by one on there corresponding socket descriptor in for loop.

This is the only way I know for doing this, which I think is not a good way because its badly hit the performance of system if user increase.

Please help me on this by suggesting me the efficient way of achieving the same.

Thanks.

Comment: TCP works like that. You can try UDP with broadcast addresses but that's all i think.

Comment: Did you have a look at how existing systems (e.g. irc) do it?

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you are doing this for real use, consider using an off-the-shelf solution. If you are doing this as an exercise, you might like to use something like redis to implement a lot of the core functionality, at least before you replace it with your own stuff.

Answer (score 2):

That is the only way you can go from my knowledge with stream sockets (i.e. TCP, which I would suggest to use for a (reliable) chat).

Multicast and others only work for UDP and such.

This is also (among others, like redundancy and so on) the reason why large IRC networks have multiple servers. A server receiving a user message then only needs to distribute to all his own users and to all the servers of the network, which then again distribute to their users. This reduces the individual server load.

Comment: @user1457812 I did not mean broadcast on the network layer but on the application layer. I corrected my wording and use *to distribute* instead. Sorry for the misunderstanding. They're doing the same thing as you do, but distributed in their network, so that each server has less peers to whom it needs to send the message.

Comment: Thanks for clearing me out. A simple concern is when user logs in from client application it sends the domain name of my application. Now if I am using lets say 2 servers in the domain then DNS will allocate a IP of single server based on load balancing. So user can be in any of the 2 servers but public room is known to both the servers. so its difficult to distribute the messages. Please correct me if I am wrong at some place.

Comment: Thats how IRC does it. The servers know each other. And if server A receives a user message, it distributes it to all its users and to server B, including the target room C. Server B knows that the message is from server A and will distribute it to all users in room C.

Answer (score 0):

Use pub sub. The clients subscribe to the chat room and you only need to publish the message to a single entity - the chat room.

Comment: How I can use this because communication is on TCP based sockets. Please guide me more with this.

Comment: How exactly does that help with the problem that the clients somehow need to be informed of new messages via a reliable connection?

Comment: Do you basically mean that he should use an off-the-shelf pub/sub system?